Forbidden access denied error despite having correct middleware functions
This is my mongoose schema for an event planning website where there are different types of services such as catering,venues etc, this is done using discriminator.
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const PackageSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  package_id: { type: Number },
  name: { type: String, required: true },
  price: { type: Number, required: true },
  description: { type: String, required: true }
});
//added
const baseOptions = {
    discriminatorKey: "type",
    collection: "Service",
};
const ServiceSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
  {
    vendor_id: {
      type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: 'User',
      required: true
    },
    packages: [PackageSchema],
    service_name: {
      type: String,
      required: true
    },
    service_type: {
      type: String,
      enum: ['decor', 'venue', 'catering', 'photography'],
      required: true
    },
    cancellation_policy: {
      type: String,
      enum: ['Flexible', 'Moderate', 'Strict'],
      required: true
    },
    staff: {
      type: String,
      enum: ['Male', 'Female'],
      required: true
    },
    description: {
      type: String,
      required: true
    },
    start_price: {
      type: Number,
      required: true
    },
    average_rating: {
      type: Number,
      default: 0,
      min: 0,
      max: 5,
    },
    location_id: {
      type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: 'Location',
      required: true
    },
  }, 
  baseOptions
 );
 const BaseService = mongoose.model('Service', ServiceSchema);

 const CateringService = BaseService.discriminator('CateringService', new mongoose.Schema({ 
    cuisine: { type: String, required: true }
    })
);

const VenueService = BaseService.discriminator('VenueService', new mongoose.Schema({ 
    capacity : { type: Number, required: true },
    outdoor  : { type: String,enum: ['outdoor', 'banquet'], required: true }
    })
);

const PhotographyService = BaseService.discriminator('PhotographyService', new mongoose.Schema({ 
    drone   : { type: Boolean, required: true },
    })
);

const DecorService = BaseService.discriminator('DecorService', new mongoose.Schema({ 
    decortype   : { type: String,
    enum: ['wedding', 'birthday party', 'anniversary', 'formal events'],
    required: true },
    })
);

ServiceSchema.pre('save', async function(next) {
  try {
    const service = this;
    // Check if the 'packages' field is modified or not
    if (service.isModified('packages')) {
      // Calculate the package_id for each package in the array
      service.packages.forEach((pkg, index) => {
        // Set the package_id to the next number
        pkg.package_id = index + 1;
      });
    }
    next();
  } catch (error) {
    next(error);
  }
});
const Service = mongoose.model('Service', ServiceSchema);

module.exports = Service;

this is my vendormiddleware to ensure only vendor or admin can add a new service such as venue. Similar code is for admin too.
function vendorMiddleware(req, res, next) {
    if (req.user && req.user.role === "vendor") {
        next();
    } else {
        return res.status(403).json({ msg: "Forbidden: Access denied!" });
    }
}

module.exports = vendorMiddleware;

and this is my route code for posting a new venue

// Place middleware here to ensure only vendor or admin can add a venue
router.use([vendorMiddleware, adminMiddleware]);

// POST endpoint to add a new venue
router.post('/newvenue', async (req, res) => {
  try {
    // Extract venue details from the request body
    const { vendor_id, capacity, outdoor, service_name, service_type, description, start_price, location_id, packages } = req.body;

    // Create a new venue service instance
    const newVenue = new VenueService({
      vendor_id,
      service_name,
      service_type,
      description,
      start_price,
      location_id,
      packages, // Assuming packages are included in the request body
      capacity,
      outdoor
    });

    // Save the new venue service to the database
    await newVenue.save();

    res.status(201).json({ msg: 'Venue added successfully!', venue: newVenue });
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
    res.status(500).json({ msg: 'Internal Server Error' });
  }
});


I have tried debugging but I dont know why i keep on getting "msg": "Forbidden: Access denied!" error when i test this on postman (doesn't matter if i am logged in as admin or vendor). The middleware functions are working just fine for adding reviews/other functions so i dont think the issue lies there.

Check putting console.log(req.user) inside your "vendorMiddleware" that is it properly receiving data from request and hitting that if condition..??

removing router.use(adminMiddleware) seems to solve the problem, but removing it means i cant identify if my user is an admin or no. Without it, i can successfully add/post a venue as a vendor. I checked my adminMiddleware code and its exactly the same as vendorMiddleware so i cannot understand why one is working and the other isn't
